# splitting string by €-symbol with PHP won't work?

Tags: php, explode, str-replace

i got this crappy website i need to parse and the html-element i need to get the contents of contains "`€`" symbols. the actual html of this page looks like this:

```
<td>Mais-Lauch-R&ouml;sti <font color=#000000 size=1>(1,2,9,11)</font> mit Paprikasauce <font color=#000000 size=1>(3,9)</font><nobr><b> 2,10 &euro;</b></nobr><br/>........
```

so i use DOM to get the contents of the  element. unfortunately, this ends up like the following code (via var_dump()):

```
string(270) "Mais-Lauch-Rösti (1,2,9,11) mit Paprikasauce (3,9) 2,10 €.........
```

(dom seems to strip all containing tags when using sth like `$td->item(0)->nodeValue;`)

so the `&euro;` was parsed to `€` - fine. but when i try to split the string (that is actually a little longer than the posted excerpt) by the €-symbol by using

```
$data = explode("€", $data);
```

it won't work. explode() just won't detect the € symbol. i tried splitting by "&euro;", but this won't work either. i also tried using str_replace() and preg_replace() - but none of them would recognize the symbol :(

am i missing something? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: ah - btw:<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

Comment: Hmmm, care to give an url of the website? Would solve a lot of character set issue-guesses a lot faster :)

Comment: its an asp-site: http://www.studentenwerk-aachen.de/essen/speiseplaene.asp select "diese woche" and check "alle auswählen". then submit by clicking on "speisepläne anzeigen". this is the site i need to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried it with simple php dom parser... it works :)

Answer (score 3):

It's still `&euro;` in the string - it just displays in the browser as €. You'll need to split on `&euro;` instead.

Comment: to quote myself: i tried splitting by "&euro;", but this won't work either

Answer (score 1):

`$data = explode("&euro;", $data);`